# Grails 4 "Static Type Checking" error only for Date objects

Tags: grails, groovy

So I am migrating from Grails 3.3.x to 4.0.13.  When I try to compile my app I am getting compilation errors when I try to use the `format` method for any Date property.  For exmaple

```
class Event {
    Date startDateTime
    Date regDeadline
}
```

Then in my GSON class I have this

```
model {
    Event event
}

json {
    eventDate event.startDateTime.format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a")
    regDeadline event.regDeadline.format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a")
}
```

I get the following compiling error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
raa_domain_grid__event_gson: 10: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.util.Date#format(java.lang.String). Please check if the declared type is correct and if the method exists.
 @ line 10, column 15.
       eventDate event.startDateTime.format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a")
                 ^
raa_domain_grid__event_gson: 11: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.util.Date#format(java.lang.String). Please check if the declared type is correct and if the method exists.
 @ line 11, column 17.
       regDeadline event.regDeadline.format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a")
```

This worked without issues before.  I suspect it has something to do with the Groovy upgrade to 2.5.6 but I don't see what that issue would be.  This is happening throughout my entire app.  All my Classes that have Dates as properties throw this error when I try to apply formatting to them.  The above is just a simple example of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found that the Date helper methods were removed in Groovy 2.5 and put into another library `groovy-dateutil`.  By adding this to my Gradle build file everything compiled as expected.